# Validating abstract meta class with dynamic fields

Tags: django

I have an abstract `Form` class that consists of dynamic fields:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, all_required=True, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['street_num'] = forms.CharField(max_length=10, label='Street number', required=all_required)
    self.fields['street_dir'] = DirectionFormField(required=all_required)
    self.fields['street_name'] = forms.CharField(max_length=35, required=all_required)
    self.fields['city'] = forms.CharField(max_length=35, required=all_required)
    self.fields['state'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_ABBREVS, required=all_required)
    self.fields['zip'] = ZipCodeFormField(max_length=5, required=all_required)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
class AddressCreateForm(AddressForm):
  name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

If I call is_valid() on a `AddressCreateForm` object in a view, I find that it always returns false.  However, no errors are returned.  If the `AddressForm` class does not have dynamic fields as below, everything works fine:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
  street_num = forms.CharField(max_length=10, label='Street number')
  street_dir = DirectionFormField()
  street_name = forms.CharField(max_length=35)
  city = forms.CharField(max_length=35)
  state = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATE_ABBREVS)
  zip = ZipCodeFormField(max_length=5)

  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

What am I missing from the class with dynamic fields?

As per Fiver's suggestion, `__init__` should begin with this:

```
class AddressForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('all_required') == None:
      all_required = True
    else:
      all_required = kwargs['all_required']
      kwargs.pop('all_required')

    super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #...
```

This works.

Comment: Not sure if it is your issue, but be careful with using keyword args before non-keyword args and using specified keywords with **kwargs. Try changing `__init__(self, all_required=True, *args, **kwargs)` to `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` and then checking for `all_required` yourself in the code to set a default. You may also need to pop that keyword as the parent init may not be expecting it.